# how to make dynamic title on laravel by fetching the data from a list of data on the backend

Tags: php, laravel, backend, laravel-8

**guest.blade.php**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="Yucel Yilmaz">
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
    <meta name="publisher" content="Yücel Yilmaz">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@yield('title') | ecommerece</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```
cities-page-component.blade.php
<div>
@section('title', 'Laundry Near Me')
</div>

listing-page-component.blade.php
<div>
@section('title', 'Laundry Near Me')
</div>
```

how do I make **Title dynamic**  in the product detail page from  the **data from the backend** in *laravel*

like an I have a list of cities, under the cities, there is a bunch of laundries.
On the main page, we can search for cities so the list of cities is shown from the database. when the user clicks any of the cities the page will be directed to another page with a list of laundries **so I want the title to be laundries in `{{ city name }}`**
same way when the user clicks on any laundry the page is directed detail page of laundries **so the title I want to be `{{ laundry name }}` in `{{ city name }}`**

Answer (score 0):

You can set `@yield` for title via template inheritance.

##### Layout

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@yield('title')</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    ...
```

Set `$dynamicTitle` in view :

```
@extends('layouts.app')
 
@section('title', $dynamicTitle)
 
@section('content')
    ...
@endsection
```

You are free to assign a value to the `@section('title')` using `$dynamicTitle` or `$item->title` for example. Depends on your needs.

Comment: Can you elaborate  the answer, because I'm also a beginner to laravel

Comment: Update your question. Include example of controller, and view @AminuAminaldo

Comment: I have updated the question, is that what you meant?

Comment: There's no `laundries` or `city` from your controller. I can't fully explain the steps from the beginning. At least you understand how the controller works with the view and send the data `laundries` or `city` from database.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the City Title as session variable in cities selection controller when returning city record with

```
session()->put('cityName', city->city_title);
```

and use it in your laundries view as

```
<h4>City Name : {{ Session('cityName') }} </h4>
```

likewise save laundry Title when returning laundry record as

```
session()->put('laundryName', laundry->laundry_title);
```

and use it in your detail view like

```
<h4>City Name : {{ Session('cityName') }} Laundry : {{ Session('laundryName') }} </h4>
```